# How can I identify what version of ubuntu is installed in a specific partition?

Tags: partitioning, live-cd

I have two versions of ubuntu installed on my laptop 10.04 and 9.10. They are installed on separate partitions (let's say /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 respectively), but I forgot which is which. I'm now booting through liveCD (I'm troubleshooting a grub issue), but I need to know which partition contains the lucid install.

I have full access to the contents of each partition, so it must be easy to find out. I just don't know which file to look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of `/etc/lsb-release` should give you the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is `/etc/issue`